# Syncing iPod through banshee

Tags: banshee, ipod

I tried "importing to library" then all the music is in my library, but when I disconnect the Ipod the music isn't playable.

Answer (score 1):

Check outh these two articles the might help.
[Uses of iPods With Banshee in Ubuntu](http://techtips.salon.com/uses-ipods-banshee-ubuntu-627.html)
[The Banshee Music Player](http://www.gnomejournal.org/article/30/the-banshee-music-player-an-introduction)